# Ionic 3: How can I navigate between views via a button and retain the side menu?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic3

I've created a demo app using Ionic CLI (sidemenu) and setup 2 views (A and B). If I navigate from view A to view B via the side menu the burger menu is visible on both views - perfect.

However, the issue I am facing is when I navigate from view A to view B via a button the burger menu disappears from view B.

My button code is:

```
<button [navPush]="viewB" ion-button block>View B</button>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to use `setRoot` instead of `Push`

Answer (score 0):

Using `setRoot` in this way would not work:

```
<button [setRoot]="viewB" ion-button block>View B</button>
```

---

So instead I setup a click function:

```
<button (click)="goToNextPage()" ion-button block clear>Login</button>
```

And inside my view A controller added:

```
  goToNextPage() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
  }
```

`navPush` adds the next view onto the top of the stack whereas `setRoot` clears the stack and resets the root view.